# How to Enable Stack Trace in Heroku without Add On

Tags: logging, heroku, stack-trace

A staging site on Heroku is throwing an error. Log level debug (heroku config:set LOG_LEVEL=debug) is not providing a full stack trace when I run the logs (heroku logs -n500 -aheroku-app-name -t).

How might I enable a stack trace without any account addons?

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for but if you set your RAILS_ENV from staging to development you can get your stack traces in your webpage just as if you were running the application locally.

Answer (score -5):

Triple checked that this works.

No terminal shortcuts- this for new folks. Maybe you marked down because it doesn't work with your particular environmental variables. However if your DEV/STAGING/PRODUCTION environments are roughly the same, this is indeed how you enable stack trace on Heroku.

---

(Thanks DJ Triple Threat!)
Here is the step-by-step for folks new to Heroku. There are terminal shortcuts as well. You can find them in the Heroku docs.

1. Login to Heroku.
2. Click on your application.
3. Click on "Settings" on the far right in the top application menu bar.
4. Under "Config Variables" click on the "Reveal Config Vars" button.
5. Change the "RAILS_ENV" setting from "staging" to "development".

Now the full stack trace error info is available. Be sure to turn this back to staging if you don't want to see the stack trace.

Comment: This isn't going to work if your app is at all different in production or development mode. For example what if you use SQLite in development and Postgres in production.

Comment: You're right that if you have rather different configuration variables you could inadvertently disable your application when you enable stack trace.  HOWEVER- this is how stack trace is enabled.

Comment: Please stop marking this down. THIS IS HOW STACK TRACE IS ENABLED ON HEROKU. If your environment variables do not support it that does not make this answer wrong.

Comment: useless to me - my entire dev setup is unsuitable for Heroku. Surely there's a better way?

Comment: Stack trace should be part of your local development environment. Do you have an application on Heroku?